# How do I merge 2D Convolutions in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, linear-algebra, convolution

From linear algebra we know that linear operators are associative.

In the deep learning world, this concept is used to justify the introduction of non-linearities between NN layers, to prevent a phenomenon colloquially known as [linear lasagna](https://youtu.be/PfNfY1xmkLs?t=75), ([reference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/335972)).

In signal processing this also leads to a well known trick to optimize memory and/or runtime requirements ([reference](http://www.dspguide.com/ch7/2.htm)).

So merging convolutions is a very useful tool from different perspectives. How to implement it with PyTorch?

Comment: "From linear algebra we know that linear operators are commutative and associative." this is not true, you can only assume associativity, commutativity is rare outside of special cases (simultaneous diagonalizability).

Comment: Oops! you are right, I mean linear systems, not operators. I will correct it and clarify. The concept of "linearity" differs which is confusing, so I will also clarify that. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Actually, I just removed it. For the record, this was my reference: http://www.dspguide.com/ch5/5.htm. There, commutativity is listed as a property for "linearity of systems". But in this question that kind of terminology is simply confusing/misleading and not needed. So thanks again!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we have `y = x * a * b` (where `*` means convolution and `a, b` are your kernels), we can define `c = a * b` such that `y = x * c = x * a * b` as follows:

```py
import torch

def merge_conv_kernels(k1, k2):
    """
    :input k1: A tensor of shape ``(out1, in1, s1, s1)``
    :input k2: A tensor of shape ``(out2, in2, s2, s2)``
    :returns: A tensor of shape ``(out2, in1, s1+s2-1, s1+s2-1)``
      so that convolving with it equals convolving with k1 and
      then with k2.
    """
    padding = k2.shape[-1] - 1
    # Flip because this is actually correlation, and permute to adapt to BHCW
    k3 = torch.conv2d(k1.permute(1, 0, 2, 3), k2.flip(-1, -2),
                      padding=padding).permute(1, 0, 2, 3)
    return k3
```

To illustrate the equivalence, this example combines two kernels with 900 and 5000 parameters respectively into an **equivalent** kernel of 28 parameters:

```py
# Create 2 conv. kernels
out1, in1, s1 = (100, 1, 3)
out2, in2, s2 = (2, 100, 5)
kernel1 = torch.rand(out1, in1, s1, s1, dtype=torch.float64)
kernel2 = torch.rand(out2, in2, s2, s2, dtype=torch.float64)

# propagate a random tensor through them. Note that padding
# corresponds to the "full" mathematical operation (s-1)
b, c, h, w = 1, 1, 6, 6
x = torch.rand(b, c, h, w, dtype=torch.float64) * 10
c1 = torch.conv2d(x, kernel1, padding=s1 - 1)
c2 = torch.conv2d(c1, kernel2, padding=s2 - 1)

# check that the collapsed conv2d is same as c2:
kernel3 = merge_conv_kernels(kernel1, kernel2)
c3 = torch.conv2d(x, kernel3, padding=kernel3.shape[-1] - 1)
print(kernel3.shape)
print((c2 - c3).abs().sum() < 1e-5)
```

**Note:** The equivalence is assuming that we have unlimited numerical resolution. I think there was research on stacking many low-resolution-float linear operations and showing that the networks profited from numerical error, but I am unable to find it. Any reference is appreciated!