# How to merge two 2D convolutions together

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, linear-algebra, convolution

“*” means convolution

Hello,

I am trying to find a way to merge two 2D convolutions together.

Assume that I have an image “Img” of dimensions (1x20x20) and two kernels “k1” and “k2” both of dimensions (1x3x3).

Normally you would first convolve Img with k1 and then convolve the result with k2:

(Img * k1) * k2

My goal is to find a kernel k3 that if applied to Img does the same thing of the expression above.
Since convolutions are linear operators this is possible. In order to do that (at least mathematically speaking) we can just first convolve k1 with k2 and then apply the result over Img:

k3 = k1 * k2

(Img * k1) * k2 = Img * (k1 * k2) = Img * k3

This formula although works well in the mathematical world, it doesn’t work at all at an implementation level. Take for instance the example above. Both k1 and k2 are of dimensions (1x3x3). If I just blindly apply the formula above and I convolve k1 with k2 then my output will be of dimension (1x1x1). This is clearly not what I want. Therefore, even in this very simple scenario, this formula is “wrong”. What we are supposed to do in this case is to pad k1 with 2 pixels in order to obtain the correct kernel k3 we are looking for.

I’ve found a code that does this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58357815/how-do-i-merge-2d-convolutions-in-pytorch).

I’ll report the code here for simplicity:

```
import torch

def merge_conv_kernels(k1, k2):
    """
    :input k1: A tensor of shape ``(out1, in1, s1, s1)``
    :input k1: A tensor of shape ``(out2, in2, s2, s2)``
    :returns: A tensor of shape ``(out2, in1, s1+s2-1, s1+s2-1)``
      so that convolving with it equals convolving with k1 and
      then with k2.
    """
    padding = k2.shape[-1] - 1
    # Flip because this is actually correlation, and permute to adapt to BHCW
    k3 = torch.conv2d(k1.permute(1, 0, 2, 3), k2.flip(-1, -2),
                      padding=padding).permute(1, 0, 2, 3)
    return k3
```

However, this code doesn’t work at all when the two convolutions have different paddings and strides.

I was wondering if it is still possible to merge convolutions together when paddings and strides are taken into consideration and if someone could provide a hint on how to do it or a working code for this more complicated scenario (PyTorch).

Thank you

Comment: The convolution of two 3x3 kernels is a 5x5 one. So (1, 3, 3) * (1, 3, 3) -> (1, 5, 5)

Answer (score 0):

When the first convolution **pad enough (up to kernel size - 1) and no stride**, you can merge your convolution with any pad/stride for the second convolution with:

```py
def merge_conv_kernels(k1, k2, s2, p2):
    # Assuming p1 = k1.shape[-1] - 1 and s1 = 1
    kernel_pad = k2.shape[-1] - 1
    k3 = torch.conv2d(k1.permute(1, 0, 2, 3), k2.flip(-1, -2),
                      padding=kernel_pad,
                      stride=1).permute(1, 0, 2, 3)
    p3 = k1.shape[-1] - 1 + p2
    s3 = s2
    return k3, s3, p3
```

If you have pad=0 in the first convolution, you can find counter-example. For instance in a `3*3` image and :

```py
kernel1 = tensor([[1, 0, -1],
                  [1, 0, -1],
                  [1, 0, -1]])
p1, s1 = 0, 1
kernel2 = ones(3, 3)
p2, s2 = 2, 1
```

Basically the combination of the two convolutions applies the kernel 1 and copy the value in a `3*3` image. You can't get it with only one convolution. First, the kernel should be of size 4 or 5 with padding 1 or 2 to get all the input values every time (or more than 5 but it leads to never used values in the kernel). Now by considering each pixel and any input matrix, we can see that the kernel must contain the kernel 1 in a all its `3*3` sub-matrices. But it is impossible due to the asymmetry of the kernel 1.

You can find similar problems with stride > 1 or padding < kernel_size - 1 in the first convolution that decreases the size of the output.